# Please check the code and give me why there is this error?

Tags: java, jquery, json

this is my servlet code

```
List<Group> list=  dao.findgroup(user);
        JSONObject json=(JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(list);
        ServletResponse response=ActionContext.getServletResponse();
        response.setContentType("text/JSON");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter(); 
        out.println(json);
        out.close();
```

//this is my jquery code

```
$.get("viewgroup.process",function(data){
        var use=$.parseJSON(data);
        $(use).each(function(i,v)
        {

        var det="<tr><td>"+v.value+"</td><td>"+v.description+"</td><td>"+v.code+"</td><td>"+v.status+"</td><td><a href='#'>reset code</a></td><td><a href='#'>change status</a></td></tr>";
        $(det).appendTo("#tablebody");
        });
```

Now my problem is when i am sending this request and getting a list as json object,and when I use method parseJSON it gives me error:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Can any one tell me why this error is there?

Comment: i have a list ,and have converted into jsonobject using jsonserlializer?amd mow its now working?any possiblity why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the `data` parameter when using `$.get` is already a javascript object (rather than a JSON string), so no need to parse it again:

```
$.get("viewgroup.process",function(data){
    var use = data;//or just use data directly rather that a new variable called use
    $(use).each(function(i,v)
    {
        var det="<tr><td>"+v.value+"</td><td>"+v.description+"</td><td>"+v.code+"</td><td>"+v.status+"</td><td><a href='#'>reset code</a></td><td><a href='#'>change status</a></td></tr>";
        $(det).appendTo("#tablebody");
    });
    //rest of code...
});
```

Comment: why the data parameter is javascript object when i am sending a json object as response?

Comment: Because that how the JQuery people decided it should work. Plus there is no such thing as a JSON object, JSON means JavaScript Object Notation and is basically just a string. JQuery `$.get` is implemented to parse that string for you, so you can work with it easier

Answer (score 0):

Change `out.println(json);` to `out.println(json.toString());` in your servlet code. You want to send out the stringified JSON, not the actual object.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29